# How do I use one regex pattern to make a String become another regex pattern in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Providing a simple example can yield to solutions that I am not asking for, and alternative solutions will not work since I got much more complicated patterns to solve.

Lets say that you have a String 123.321

This String can be represented with regex as `[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*`
What I want to do is replace "." with "," to obtain 123,321.

Therefore, I want the regex pattern `[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*`  to become a regex pattern  `[0-9]*,[0-9]*`

Is it possible to indicate two regex patterns and make a String that matches the first pattern become a String that matches the second pattern?

How would I do it ?

What would be the simplest solution?

Comment: Is it always palindromic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  if you have two capture groups, and then print out the two capture groups with a comma, is this not what you want?

Comment: No, like I said, want to provide two regex patterns and a String that matches the first pattern, in order to transform it in such a way that would give a result that matches the second pattern.  I believe I was very brief on what I want to accomplish. Lets assume that this can be done, and that I will not have patterns where transformation cannot be done at all.

Comment: But yes, you did give me another idea with capture groups, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\\d*` to match optional digits and group the digit matches with `()`. Then use [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like

```
String str = "123.321";
if (str.matches("\\d*\\.\\d*")) {
  str = str.replaceAll("(\\d*)\\.(\\d*)", "$1,$2");
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
123,321
```

Comment: great! It does help! Capture groups can be a solution to a problem I want to solve... Not a full-answer I expected, but it will work.